# With Xamarin ... How do I SUM two cells inside the grid for the same row or for several rows?

Tags: c#, xamarin, grid

Please help, as I made a small project with Xamarin

It is a connection to a SQl server database and then filling the Datatable with data and then displaying the data in Grid .. which contains Entries that have been added programmatically and not in XAML ... This means that Entries do not have Names or IDs assigned to each one of them .. Even these At the moment it is working fine...and the data is being recalled properly
But as you know inside Grid there are Rows and Columns and I need to add or multiply the contents of Entries in the same row or add the contents of a column or columns

How do I SUM two cells inside the grid for the same row or for several rows?
And does the grid fit with that or do I have to choose another rendering too

Notes ::: >>>  Maingrid is my Grid

```
////// define the number of rows according to the number of item you have
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }

        //////// defining column number (in this case 3)
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }

        ////////// adding the items to the grid (3 column , RN rows)

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            

            for (int num = 0; num < dt.Columns.Count; num++)
            {
                
                

                    Entry entry = new Entry();
                    entry.Text = dt.Rows[i][num].ToString();
                    entry.TextColor = Color.Blue;
                    entry.BackgroundColor = Color.GhostWhite;
                    entry.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
                    entry.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                    entry.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                    entry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
                    entry.TextChanged += MyEntry_TextChanged;
                    entry.WidthRequest = 50;
                                            
                   
                    MainGrid.Children.Add(entry, num , i);
               

        }
```

Comment: If you want a spreadsheet-ish UI you should use a DataGrid

Comment: Read about MVVM and Data Binding. Each cell’s text should be bound to a property that holds the value. Then you write code to work with the properties. If one cell is bound to A, another to B, and a sum cell bound to C, then code is C = A + B; Get that much to work, then read about binding to array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two cells at first. And then get the sum of the two cell and set it as another cells value.

You can try the following code:

```
        public void GetSum()
        {
            var rowcount = MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
            for( int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++ )
            {
               Entry A = (Entry)MainGrid.Children.Where(view => Grid.GetRow(view) == i && Grid.GetColumn(view) == 0 ).FirstOrDefault();
               Entry B = (Entry)MainGrid.Children.Where(view => Grid.GetRow(view) == i && Grid.GetColumn(view) == 1 ).FirstOrDefault();
               Entry C = (Entry)MainGrid.Children.Where(view => Grid.GetRow(view) == i && Grid.GetColumn(view) == 2 ).FirstOrDefault();
               C.Text = (int.Parse(A.Text) + int.Parse(B.Text)).ToString();
            }
        }
```

The code above can make your MainGrid like a grid in the picture below:

[image]

In addition, the point is this line `MainGrid.Children.Where(view => Grid.GetRow(view) == i && Grid.GetColumn(view) == 0 ).FirstOrDefault()`. You can use it to get any child in the grid if you know the child view's row index and column index.